# Can you bind an event to access keys?

Tags: javascript, html, events, accessibility

As you probably know, in HTML there's the `accesskey` attribute which lets you assign a key to elements so you can trigger/focus them directly with the keyboard, without having to tab to them first.

Now I was wondering, if you can bind a JS event to that exact... event, or do you have to go the old-fashioned way and listen for `onkeypress` (for example) and then check for the key combination?

The latter would kind of defeat the purpose, since [browsers have different key combinations to trigger access keys](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_accesskey.asp).

My idea behind this was assigning an access key to the (mega menu) navigation, which would unfold and focus it, so you can then tab through the links. That way I can put the navigation at the end of the HTML, so users don't have to tab through hundreds of links (exaggeration) before they can reach the links in the actual content area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such event, for instance no onAccessKey event you would have to hook one of the onkey* events.

However the accesskey does trigger some activation events for elements when the accesskey is used (tested with chrome and firefox). So you can simply use those events like you would normally as if the user clicked,focused,changed that part of the UI.

1. Display elements, i.e. div,span, etc:

   - onclick
2. input elements, i.e. text,textarea:

   - onfocus, if not previously focused
   - onclick in some browsers
3. input elements, i.e. radio,checkbox:

   - onfocus, if not previously focused
   - onclick
   - onchange, if not previously checked
4. select elements:

   - onfocus, if not previously focused
   - onclick, if not previously selected
5. select element options (triggered on select element):

   - onfocus, if select box not previously focused
   - onclick, if select box not previously selected
   - onchange, if option not previously selected

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekbx5squ/)

An example of using it to open a menu

html

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menuBtn" accesskey="r">Menu</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery("#menuBtn").click(function(){
   jQuery(this).next().toggle(); 
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6y9xu9h/)

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea it triggers an `onclick` event on `<div>`s and thelike.

Comment: ...and it doesn't in IE 11. Just sayin'